# ¿Se puede ver instancias en Azure como en Monitis?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Lo que se requiere es tener una visión de todos los servidores en uno solo, como monitis por ejemplo. ¡Help!

Comment: Estimada Tatiana, podrías darle una leída a: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask saludos :D

Comment: gracias Fredy :)